# Posting a runnable to a View that invalidates the View sometimes doesn't work

Tags: android, asynchronous, android-view, android-handler

I been fighting an odd issue these last few days.  I have a custom ExpandableListAdapter where each row contains an ImageView, among other things.  I have a class that handles the asynchronous loading of images from the multitude of places they may reside (disk cache, app data, remote server, etc).  In my adapter's getView method I delegate the responsibility of returning a View to the list Item itself (I have multiple row types for my group list).  I request the image load as follows:

```
final ImageView thumb = holder.thumb;
holder.token = mFetcher.fetchThumb(mImage.id, new BitmapFetcher.Callback() {

            @Override
            public void onBitmap(final Bitmap b) {
                thumb.post(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        thumb.setImageBitmap(b);
                    }
                });
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure() {
            }
        });
```

Yeah, it's ugly, but I decided against some contract where you have the BitmapFetcher.Callback execute its methods on the UI thread by default.

Anyway, when I load the Activity that contains the ExpandableListView there will often be thumb images missing from different rows in the list.  Reloading the Activity may cause some of the missing thumbs to show but others that were previously showing may not be anymore.  The behavior is pretty random as far as I can tell.  Scrolling the ListView such that the rows with missing images get recycled causes the new thumb images (when the recycled row gets displayed again) to load fine.  Scrolling back to rows that previously contained missing images causes the missing images to appear.  I can confirm that all the images are loading correctly from my BitmapFetcher (mFetcher) class.  I should also mention that I load other images in other places.  Every once in awhile they don't appear either.

After pulling most of my hair out, I discovered that changing:

```
thumb.post(new Runnable() {
```

to:

```
mExpListView.post(new Runnable() {
```

fixes the issue.  I originally thought that the issue might be happening because I was using a final reference to a View, but the other locations in the app use non-final references to a view to post messages, and, as I mentioned, sometimes those did not work.  I eventually changed everything to use an Activity's runOnUiThread() method (and my own getUiThreadRunner().execute method when inside Fragments) and that seems to fix the issue all around.

So my question remains, in what cases can View.post() to fail to deliver the runnable to the associated ViewRoot's message queue in the proper order?  Or, perhaps the invalidate() is happening before the View is returned from getView and thus before it's placed in a ViewGroup that can be reached from the root View.  Those are really the only cases I can think of that would prevent the image from showing up.  I can guarantee that none of these calls are happening until at least onStart has finished executing.  Further, it looks like it's fine to post to a View even if it hasn't been attached to a Window yet:

```
// Execute enqueued actions on every traversal in case a detached view enqueued an action
getRunQueue().executeActions(attachInfo.mHandler);
```

(in performTraversal).  The only difference between the runOnUiThread and post seems to be that an Activity has a different Handler than the ViewRootImpl.

Activity:

```
final Handler mHandler = new Handler();
```

whereas in ViewRootImpl:

```
final ViewRootHandler handler = new ViewRootHandler();
```

But, this should not be a problem provided both Handlers were constructed in the same Thread (or using the same Looper).  That leaves me wondering if it is, indeed, a problem to invalidate() a View that has not yet been added to the hierarchy.  For this to be the case invalidate should either 1. not do anything if it's not visible, or 2. only be valid for the next performTraversal() that happens.

View.invalidate() checks a nice private method that's not documented called skipInvalidate():

```
/**
 * Do not invalidate views which are not visible and which are not running an animation. They
 * will not get drawn and they should not set dirty flags as if they will be drawn
 */
private boolean skipInvalidate() {
    return (mViewFlags & VISIBILITY_MASK) != VISIBLE && mCurrentAnimation == null &&
            (!(mParent instanceof ViewGroup) ||
                    !((ViewGroup) mParent).isViewTransitioning(this));
}
```

It looks like number 1 is more accurate!  However, I would think this only pertains to a View's VISIBILITY property.  So, is it accurate to assume that a View is considered *not* VISIBLE if it cannot be reached from the ViewRoot?  Or is the VISIBILITY property unaffected by the View's container?  If the former is the case (which I suspect it is) it raises a concern.  My use of Activity.runOnUiThread is not a solution to the problem.  It only happens to work because the invalidate() calls are being sent to a different Handler and being executed *later* (after getView returns and after the row has been added and made visible on the screen).  Has anybody else run into this issue?  Is there a good solution?

Answer (score 1):

Hey David I ran into a similar issue long time back. The basic requirement for `view.post(Runnable r)` is that the `view` should be attached to the window for Runnable to be executed. However, since you are loading images asynchronously in your first case, therefore there is a probability that `imageView` aren't attached to window when post request is made and hence, some images fail to load.

Quoting earlier version of docs on the same:

> *View.post()* : Causes the Runnable to be added to the message queue. The runnable will be run on the user interface thread. This method can
>   be invoked from outside of the UI thread **only when this View is
>   attached to a window.**

Switching to you next question, what is the best solution to handle this situation ?

Can't comment on the best solution. However, I think both `handler.post()` and `activity.runOnUIThread()` are good to go. Since, they basically post runnable in main thread queue irrespective of anything and in general, the request to display list rows would be enqueued prior to our `thumb.post()`. So, they might work flawlessly for most cases. (Atleast I've never faced a problem with them !). However. if you find a better solution, do share it with me.

Comment: PS: The new version of Android Docs seems to have edited `view.post()` entry. However, you can verify it by a little googling !

Comment: Hmm this is interesting.  You seem to have come to the same conclusion as I have.  I believe you about the docs, however, I would assume that since this clause has been removed from the docs, the functionality has changed accordingly.  If you look at the snip-it I included from RootViewImpl, you'll see that it seems the intended behavior is now to execute all actions posted to the RootView's Handler even if a View is detached from the window.  The new development would then be that detached views do not invalidate.  Given this info, does your interpretation change at all?

Answer (score 0):

**Try this : setBitmap() like this :**

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                thumb.setImageBitmap(b);
            }
        });
```

Comment: Yes, If you read the entire thing I've also suggested that this works.  I've then commented that this is not a solution because it's strictly timing that makes the difference.  Posting to the View *should* work unless there's something I'm missing or there's a bug I don't know about or the functionality is intended but not documented.